# Split a larger string and stop if a particular character is found

Tags: c++, string, sstream

The input is a standard string input. Like this.

"Anand,Ramesh,Suresh#Anand,Ramesh,Suresh,Suresh,Anand"

I want to get get all the Names before the # and store it in an array. And use the names after the # to do some operation.

How do I copy the first three names before # to an array. So far I've figured out how to copy string seperated by comma. I couldn't find a solution to stop after a particular element is found.How do I stop when I encounter a #. Here is my code so far:

```
void findCombination(string input)
{
   stringstream ss(input); 
   string buffer; 
   vector<string>names;
   int i=0; 

   while(getline(ss,buffer,','))
   {
         names.push_back(buffer); 
   }


   for(int i=0;i<names.size();i++)
           cout << names[i] <<endl; 

   //return NULL; 

}
```

Comment: 1.do splitting on `#`. 2. then again do splitting according to `,` on 0th index.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I used a vector to take the first substring before the #. And tried to assign the value to ss(sstream) using ss << substream[0]. but this didn't work for some reason. 0th location has the string before the #

Comment: try a first `getline()` with `#` as separator

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways doing it.  THe simplest would be:

```
void findCombination(string input)
{
   string filteredinput(input,0, input.find('#'));  
   stringstream ss(filteredinput);  
   ... // rest of your code unchanged
}
```